# Eclipse & unsatisfied or ambiguous dependencies for injection point:

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee, cdi, inject

I have question about Eclipse warning and CDI @Inject.

I have code for email validation (CDI bean):

```
@Named(value = "emailValidator")
@ApplicationScoped
@FacesValidator("emailValidator")
public class EmailValidator extends AbstractCDIBean<EmailValidator> implements Validator {
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Inject
    private  UserLocal                 userLocal;
    ...
```

It works, but Eclipse says:

> > No bean is eligible for injection to the injection point [JSR-299 §5.2.1] (Unsatisfied or ambiguous dependencies for injection point).

What am I doing wrong? Eclipse is latest version.

```
private UserLocal userLocal;
```

Class is local interfaces for calling a EJB beans `(public interface UserLocal{ methods...})`

Answer (score 2):

You want to replace `@Inject` by `@EJB` or you want to put `@Dependent` scope to your EJB implementation.

The reason is that `@Inject` wants scope-aware beans only.

For future reference please use [these troubleshooting tips](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v8r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/info/ae/ae/tweb_troubleshoot_cdi.html)

Comment: This is a good answer. In the jboss kitchensink examples there is typically a package.util.Resources bean, and it is not annotated with a scope. I added @Dependent to fix the warnings and deploy problems.